# TS bug in VSCode creating red squiggly lines

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

I'm getting TS errors in a Javascript project (no TS whatsoever), and the VSCode IDE is not able to read the code properly. This behaviour is random, sometimes it appears, othertime it does not. The errors make no sense whatsoever, and the code is valid.

How to fix this? Is this a bug in VSCode?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to restart VS Code.

Weird red squiggly lines are often caused by the TS Language Server having hiccups, this can most of the time be fixed by simply reloading VS Code.

Comment: This is a good workaround, thanks.